# Beginner Developing Theme with Bootstrap - NavMenu question

Tags: php, themes

I am trying to develop a theme but I am having problems with calling upon the nav menu correctly to work with Bootstrap. I am able to add the class to the "ul" section but not the corresponding "li" with the proper class.

Can anyone help me fix the code to properly setup the navigation part of my theme development. Thanks.

Below is my header.php code.

```
<!-- Bootstrap Nav Bar -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://publifiedlabs.com">
                    <img src="https://publifiedlabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/main-logo.png" alt="<?php //get alt tag for image ?>">
                    </a>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                        <?php 
                                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                                        'theme_location'=>'primary',
                                        'container'=>false,
                                        'menu_class'=>'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                                        'container_class'=>'nav-item'
                                        ) 
                                    ); ?>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how the html is currently being outputted

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
<ul id="menu-pbf-main-menu" class="navbar-nav ml-auto"><li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-16"><a href="https://publifiedlabs.com/sandbox-theme/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="https://publifiedlabs.com/sandbox-theme/about-us/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-33"><a href="#">test1</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32"><a href="https://publifiedlabs.com/sandbox-theme/blog/">Blog</a></li>
</ul>                    </div>
```

Comment: _"Here is how the html is currently being outputted"_ ... okay. How do you want it to be outputted?

Comment: WordPress' default navbars don't play well with Bootstrap. To get Bootstrap-friendly markup you'll need a custom walker. A Bootstrap walker is freely available here: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker